# MySQL How can I make query that gets info from my junction table as well as data that is not in that junction

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join, union

So to start off some back ground info, I have 3 tables one for shows, one for networks, and one for the relationship between them.

I was asked to write a query that would show the title of the show and the network it is shown on AND any networks that I do not have data for a show that's on them.

The only solution I came up with technically works but i can't help but feel like there is a much better solution. Here's the query i wrote.

```
SELECT s.title,n.name 
FROM shows s 
    JOIN networks n
    JOIN shows_networks ns          (this is the junction table)
        ON ns.show_id = s.id AND ns.network_id = n.id
UNION(
    SELECT NULL as title,name 
    FROM networks 
    WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT network_id FROM shows_networks)
);
```

Comment: you have already all information, we only usually put the junction table in the middle, so that the structure is cleare. As we don't know what you exactly want or how the tabkes actually are. we can not help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `left join`s:

```
select s.title, n.name
from networks n
left join shows_networks sn on sn.network_id = n.id
left join shows s on s.id = sn.show_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a left join nested query, something like this:

```
select s.title, n.name, z.title, z.name
from shows s 
    left join networks n on n.show_id = s.id
    left join shows_networks ns on ns.network_id = n.id          -- (this is the junction table)
    left join (
        select n2.show_id, null as title, n2.name
        from networks n2
        where n2.id not in(select network_id from shows_networks)
    ) as z on z.show_id = s.id
```

Maybe instead of `null as title`, can be something like `'missing' as title` or whatever.